# vb.net get result of sql statement

Tags: vb.net

Hello take a look at the code below:

```
Try

con.ConnectionString = strCon

Dim strCommand as String = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
                        FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
                        WITH FILE = 1
                        GO"

Dim cm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strCommand, con)

con.Open()

cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Does anyone know how to get the list of logical files for my database, it does not work with executereader. i want to get the mdf and ldf files name for my database backup file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I've said before - the `GO` is **NOT** a T-SQL keyword - drop that!

And secondly, you don't need a `WITH FILE` when restoring only the file headers - try this:

```
Dim strCommand as String = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
                           FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'"
```

This will return several pieces of data - so you need to deal with a result set and thus use `.ExecuteReader()` to get this data from the query.

Try this code (it's C#, but should be easy enough to convert to VB.NET):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace GetPhysicalDbNames
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string stmt = @"RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\temp\AW2012.BAK'";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=master;integrated Security=SSPI"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, conn))
            {
                DataTable tblInfo = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                dap.Fill(tblInfo);

                foreach (DataRow row in tblInfo.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Logical name: {0}", row["LogicalName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Physical file name: {0}", row["PhysicalName"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Executing that `RESTORE` command returns a result set, which contains among other two columns `LogicalName` and `PhysicalName` (which is the actual, complete physical file name of the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files)

Comment: i did it but still i cannot get the .mdf and .ldf files, any idea of how these can be obtained?

Comment: does not work, it says invalid attempt to read data when no data is present. :(

Comment: Its working now man, thanks a lot, you dnt know how grateful i am to you, million thanks :)

Comment: @avi if it worked for you could you please mark it as an answer so that when ppl do find your question in their search result they would know it does have an answer..thnx